# How do I fix gcp cloud run error 505, "Service Unavailable"?

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

My docker container is working fine I guess, because I can start it localy. But when I want to connect to it, deployed on Cloud Run, my browser is showing "Service Unavailable". I searched the logs files and I could find:

[Logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GVZBr.png)

I read the article https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/troubleshooting#timeout-503 but no solution was fitting. I changed the timeout time, but it never reached the time. In the Log Explorer I find the Error:

```
{
  insertId: "xy"
  labels: {1}
  logName: "**"
  receiveTimestamp: "2022-04-01T18:03:00.150646216Z"
  resource: {2}
  severity: "ERROR"
  textPayload: "Uncaught signal: 6, pid=25, tid=25, fault_addr=0."
  timestamp: "2022-04-01T18:03:00.146926628Z"
}
```

Comment: Your application was sent **signal number 6**. That means SIGABRT. Your program crashed.

Answer (score -1):

I´v found a work around. I simply had to create a production build of my react script. It probably isn´t a real solution to the problem, but at least it works for now.
I hope this can help anyone with similar problems